# Area 51 proposal: Science Educators

Tags: discussion, area51

I recently proposed Science Educators, a site where teachers and tutors of any field of science (chemistry, physics, biology, earth sciences) can ask questions.

I decided to join forces with all sciences since Mathematics Educators is not getting sufficient traffic, therefore I considered it unlikely that any of the sites could get launched an Educators site on there own.

So, if you are interested, please follow the proposal, and create and vote for example questions.

Since the old one was closed, here is a new proposal:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Science Educators]

Comment: I was looking for something like this but I think proposal ads in metas are frowned upon and hence the two downvotes you got. Anyway +1 from me.